# How to get the text file which is uploaded from android device and store it in a folder using django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views, django-file-upload

I want to save the text file or zip file in folder which can be uploaded in mobile devices(Android,IOS) using django framework.How to get the file in request ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question, this should be the answer. In your models.py file add a column for storing this upload:

```
yourfield = models.FileField(upload_to=path_of_the_folder_where_you_want_to_save)
```

And make the form on this model.